# How many different permutations p with the length n are there, so that the cycle that contains 1 has length b (1<=b<=n) and so that p(1)=2

Tags: combinatorics

How many different permutations $p$  with length $n$ are there, so that the cycle that contains $1$ has length $b$ ($1\leq b\leq n$) and so that $p(1)=2$?

I have tried for hours and still I couldn't manage to find the answer, help is appreciated!

Comment: Well, if $p(1)=2$, then yu can not have a cycle of length $1$. So pick $b-2$ elements (you are putting $1$ and $2$ too in the cycle), put them in a cycle(remember that the cycles dont mind about cyclic shuffles) and shuffle everything else.

Comment: yes I understand that I can't have a cycle of length 1. do you mean n-2 elements instead of b-2 ? so if i shuffle everything else there are (n-2)! possibilities , but thats only for b = 2

Comment: So lets do an example..you have a $5$ permutation and you want that the cycle of $1$ have $3$ elements..Then you know for sure that $1$ and $2$ are in the cycle..so you choose one(call it $c$) from the remaining $(5-2)=3$ elements. Now you have the elements in your cycle say $(1,2,c)$, so the others can be shuffle in any order ($2!$). So you will need to shuffle(cyclic permutation) your cycle and know that the number of ways to choose $c$ is ${5-2}\choose{1}$

Comment: yes I understand that but the task is to find out for  some random n and any b and thats my problem, those are too many scenarios for me to understand, i have no clue how to find out

Comment: Just change the numbers in the example for letters. The $2!$ was the $(n-b)!$, the ${5-2}\choose{1}$ was the ${n-2}\choose{c-2}$...

Comment: so what now? we only viewed this special case, sry if the solution is obvious to you, it certainly isnt to me

Comment: What do you mean by a special case? We saw an example and see that the procedure doesnt depend on the numbers, so we changed the numbers in the example by the general terms. do not worry, glad to help. So, you know how to shuffle the remaining elements and you know how to choose the elements in the cycle, you just have left to see in how many ways can you write the cycle. By the multiplication principle, you would have your answer.

Comment: In our example, are there (5-2)* 2! = 6 possibilities? Is the generell solution (n-(n-b)) * (n-b)! ?

Comment: nop, you missed choosing the elements and the $(n-(n-b))$ part i do not get it. Well, you now have a spoiled answer there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $b=1$ is an impossibility as a cycle of length one that includes $1$ must have $\pi(1)=1$, not $\pi(1)=2$.  Consider the case for when $b\geq 2$

- Pick the $b-2$ remaining members of the cycle of length $b$ that includes $1$ followed by $2$ out of the $n-2$ possible remaining:

> $\binom{n-2}{b-2}$ choices

- Order the selections of the previous step within the cycle of length $b$:

> $(b-2)!$ choices

- Permute the remaining $n-b$ elements without regard to cyclic structure:

> $(n-b)!$ choices

Applying multiplication principle:

> $\binom{n-2}{b-2}(b-2)!(n-b)! = \frac{(n-2)!}{(n-b)!(b-2)!}(b-2)!(n-b)! = (n-2)!$

Comment: Thank you that helped me a lot! Now let's say we don't need p(1) = 2 anymore but instead 1 and 2 have to be  in the same cycle b, what exactly would that change? there still would be $\binom{n-2}{b-2}$ choices and (n-b)! permutations of the remaining elements, but I think we don't have (b-2)! choices anymore?